# Have I bought wrong DDR3 RAM memory?

Tags: memory, ddr3

For my older computer I bought a new DDR3 RAM memory based on description of my friend. However, when I tried to install it I have discovered, that newly bought modules are different from the existing (they are "higher" as seen on image below) and I was unable to succesfully install them by pushing to the slot until they "click" (which I was able to do with old memory modules just fine). Have I bought wrong memory or should I just try it again?

[image: new module on left, existing on the right]

Comment: Are they both 1.5V modules? Similar speeds? If so then as long as they fit in the slot they are probably fine, it's just that the shorter module is, well, shorter...

Comment: I can only see that both are Kingston modules and they look as if they have the same amount of pins, but I can't read the labels.

Comment: If you line up an old and a new module next to each other and the slot is in exactly the same place, thus confirming they should fit it the same slot, then yes, you should try again. It can take a worrying amount of pressure to install some RAM sticks.

Comment: I've just discovered, that image on e-shop site is different from the actual product - see https://www.tsbohemia.cz/kingston-2gb-1333mhz-ddr3-kvr13n9s6-2-_d230932.html (in Czech only, sorry)

Comment: I would agree with Andrew and Mokubai, try again. Apply a little more pressure to the module with both hands, but not too much. Turning the computer if needed or putting it on a table with good light might help too (opposed to a dark place under the desk).

Comment: Hope you are using anti-static protection, if you don't all will be fine for a while (may be a year, may be less, maybe more), the it will …

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, I finally managed to install memory modules by a "bigger push".